# Ошибка при сравнении строк

Tags: java

При выполнении метода:

```
public static boolean IsMp3(File f)
{
    String s = "";
    s = f.toString();
    String[] strings  = s.split("\\.");
    if(strings[strings.length -1].trim().toLowerCase() == "mp3")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

сравниваются строки `strings[strings.length -1].trim().toLowerCase()` и `"mp3"` вопрос заключается в том, почему когда первая строка `"mp3"` функция все равно возвращает false

Answer (score 6):

Надо использовать метод `equals()`. Если хотите, чтобы строки проверялись через `==`, необходимо вызывать метод `intern()` у строки.

```
public static boolean IsMp3(File f)
{
    String s = "";
    s = f.toString();
    String[] strings  = s.split("\\.");
    return strings[strings.length -1].trim().toLowerCase().equals("mp3")
}
```

Comment: Еще есть методы `startsWith` и `endsWith`.

Answer (score 4):

Оператор `==` проверяет идентичность операндов, в случае с примитивами будет сраниваться значение, а в случае с объектами (String является объектом) будут сравниваться указатели на эти объекты в памяти (если мне не изменяет память) - фактически, проверяется, что справа и слева от `==` стоит один и тот же объект. Таким образом в данном примере вы не сравниваете две строки, а проверяете, является ли объект слева объектом справа, что, конечно, может являться правдой только в случае внутренней оптимизации JVM, которая имеет право переиспользовать уже созданную единожды строку. Как было правильно замечено выше, для соответствия оюъектов необходимо использовать метод `.equals()` - он есть у каждого объекта и может быть переопределен (что бывает очень полезно в непримитивных ситуациях - например, для сравнения двух объектов, извлеченных из базы данных надо проверять соответствие их ключей друг другу).